# What is the problem with the following antlr4 grammar

Tags: antlr4

I'm having trouble parsing a simple grammar.  I believe the issue is that there are conflicting rules.  Here is the text I'm trying to parse:

```
  redis 6.2.6-debian-10-r49 Running
  account-migrator 0.83.0 Pending
```

This represents services that have a name, version and status.  Here is the grammar that isn't working:

```
main                : statusLine+;
statusLine          : serviceName versionNumber status;
serviceName         : SERVICE_NAME;
versionNumber       : VERSION_NUMBER;
status              : STATUS;

SERVICE_NAME        : [a-zA-Z-]+;
VERSION_NUMBER      : [a-zA-Z0-9-]+ ('.' [a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*;
STATUS              : [a-zA-Z]+;
WS                  : [ \n\t]+ -> skip;
```

I believe my grammar confuses the status for a service name because my visitor finds nothing for status on the first visit, but the second visit gets the status of the first line as the service name of the second.

So the question I have is, what can I do to parse these lines correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple rules that match the same input. Everything which `STATUS` could match, will actually be matched by `SERVICE_NAME`. Check out this parse tree:

[image]

The token `STATUS` is never produced, but `Running` became a `SERVICE_NAME` token.

So, instead of trying to add semantics to the lexer (by using different names, and hence meaning, for the same input) use a common lexer rule:

```
main                : statusLine+;
statusLine          : serviceName versionNumber status;
serviceName         : IDENTIFIER;
versionNumber       : VERSION_NUMBER;
status              : IDENTIFIER;

IDENTIFIER:     [a-zA-Z-]+;
VERSION_NUMBER: [a-zA-Z0-9-]+ ('.' [a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*;

WHITE_SPACE: [ \u000B\t\r\n] -> skip;
```

which then gives you the proper parse tree:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!  What did you use to produce that parse tree?

Comment: This is from my [ANTLR4 extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4)

Comment: Thank you for your help--it's been years since I worked with antlr and I just picked it back up.  I totally get it now.